# Hutcheson's t-test

Tags: t-test

I'm trying to find out how to perform Hutcheson's t-test for significance on Shannon-Wiener Indices.

Does anybody know the formula, or how this can be performed in Excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022519370901244) you will find the original publication by Hutcheson

The formula, as well as Excel sheet for calculating it, can be found at [this address](http://www.dataanalytics.org.uk/Publications/S4E2e%20Support/exercises/Comparing%20shannon%20diversity.htm#ttest)